# How to use the returned value of a javascript function for validation in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, return-value, synchronous

I have one function that's called onSubmit of a form and checks if the image I want to upload has the needed ratio.
If the image has the ratio, it allows processing. Otherwither it wont.
The problem occurs when my function hasRatio last for several seconds, I get "undefined" instead of "TRUE" or "ANY MESSAGE".
I tried to use PROMISE but I don't really know how to handle it.
Can you please tell me what's wrong with my code?

Here are my functions:

```
$('.form-assync').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let $e = $(this);
    let $formClasses = $e.attr('class');
    let $x = $formClasses.split(' ');
    if ($x.indexOf('wait') !== -1) {
      //Display error here

    } else {

      let $image = document.getElementById("image");

      if (($image != null && $image.files.length !== 0)) {
        
        //special check for images with ratio
        let $imageClasses = $('#image').attr('class');
        let $allowProcessing = false;
        if ($imageClasses.indexOf('with-ratio') !== -1) {
          
          //check if the image has the required ratio
          let validation = async () => {
            $allowProcessing = await hasRatioOne();
            return $allowProcessing;
          }
          validation().then(function (text) {
            $allowProcessing = text; //return TRUE or any error message
          });

        } else {
          $allowProcessing = true;
        }
        
        //Process or not
        if ($allowProcessing !== true) {
          alert($allowProcessing);
          return false; //stop form submit
        }

        //Make an AJAX call here with progress bar
          

      } else {

        //Make an AJAX call without progress bar 
        
      }
      return false;
    }
  });
  
  function hasRatioOne() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        /*
            Here I will perform tasks to check if the image has ratio
            and the tasks lasts for some seconds            
        */
        let $error = "Your image has no ratio";
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve($error);
        }, 1000);
    });
  }
  
  function hasRatioTwo(){
      return true; //function doesn't last at all
  }
```

I tried to use also callback but the result always come after my alert popup

```
function hasRatioThree(callback){
    let $error = "Your image has no ratio";
    setTimeout(function () {
        callback($error);
    }, 1000);
}

hasRatioThree(function(result){
    allowProcessing = result;
});
```

As you can see, if I use "hasRatioTwo" I don't have problem but when I use "hasRatioOne" I have "undefined".

Thanks in advance for your help.